# How to add custom HTML tags in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, sublimetext3, typeahead

In ST3 if you type `<st` in an HTML field it shows known tags for autocompletion:

[image: autocompletion example]

For my templating engine TYPO3 Fluid i need to add custom tags (like `<f:for each="" as=""></f:for>`).

How can i do this?

Regular snippets are not enough here as long as they don't show up in the nice typeahead.

Comment: Open with winrar Packages/HTML.sublime-package and edit: html_completions.py

Comment: This way won't survive updates and is not distributable via sublime-package...

Comment: You can add read-only attribute.

Comment: Then the update won't do what it should. Also you can't put it into a sublime-package.

Comment: There is no other way.

Comment: @Krzysiek - yes, there is. See below.

Comment: Why won't Sublime's `Menu/Tools/New Snippet` work exactly? I've used it to create custom formats for pre-existing HTML tags' snippets, so I don't see why it couldn't be used to create snippets for new tags. Also, what is "typeahead"?

Comment: @janaspage i updated the picture to show what's meant by typehead

Comment: @Conic, was my answer below at all close to what you're seeking?

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 7):

Contrary to what was posted in the comments, there is a very straightforward way of doing this using a custom [`.sublime-completions`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) file for HTML. These files are great because not only can you just have a simple list of custom tags, but you can also use [snippet syntax](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html) for more complex tasks.

Create `Packages/User/HTML.sublime-completions` with JSON syntax, and use the following as a starting point:

```json
{
    "scope": "text.html - source - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "ffor", "contents": "<f:for each=\"$1\" as=\"$2\">$0</f:for>" },
        { "trigger": "foobar", "contents": "<foobar>$0</foobar>" },

        "baz",
        "quux",
        "thneed"            
    ]
}
```

When you type `ffor` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, `<f:for each="" as=""></f:for>` will be inserted, with the cursor between the `each` quotes. Hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> again puts the cursor between the `as` quotes, and hitting it once more puts it between the opening and closing tag. The `foobar` trigger just creates a regular `<foobar></foobar>` tag with the cursor between them. `baz`, `quux`, and `thneed` just populate the completions list with those words.

Comment: I really like the solution. Still, it doesn't enable the autocompletions to show up in the typeahead. Seems like i should make a feature request for this...

Answer (score 2):

I'm unfamiliar with the syntax you're trying to produce, but is there any reason this snippet (`Menubar / Tools / New Snippet…`) won't work for you?

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[f:for each="$1" as="$2"></f:for>]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>f:for</tabTrigger>
  <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

The `$1` and `$2` indicate cursor placement after the autocompletion (pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> jumps the cursor from the first cursor location to the second).

As it's written above, the snippet appears upon typing simply `<f` (or the complete trigger, `<f:for`) in an HTML file.

The snippet must be named with a `.sublime-snippet` file extension, and it must be saved in the `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User` directory. No relaunch of the Sublime app is necessary.

[image: autocomplete]

[image: cursor placement]

Documentation:

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Answer (score 0):

I also asked a similar question recently in [Stack overflow - How to add custom auto completion in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191460/how-to-add-custom-auto-completion-in-sublime-text-3) and [sublime User Echo](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/458420-how-to-add-custom-auto-completion-in-sublime-text-3/).

This question will be easily solved by the below implementation. (But my question is not completely solved by this method.) The method below is specific for my own problem. But you can easily figure it out how to change it.

Easiest way to implement these auto completions is to create `HTML.sublime-completions` file in `Sublime Text Build 3059 x64\Data\Packages\User` folder. (Since I use portable version of ST3 in Windows OS, the folder may be different when you installed ST3.) Filling the file with JSON text like

```
{
    "scope": "text.html - source - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "eq", "contents": "<eq>$1</eq>" },
        { "trigger": "eqq", "contents": "<eqq>\n\t$1\n</eqq>" }
    ]
}
```

. But `tab` triggering is not enabled, although my `Preferences - Settings - User` includes tab related features like

```
{
    [
        "Vintage",
        "BracketHighlighter",
        "SideBarEnhancements"
    ],
    "tab_completion": true,
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "use_tab_stops": false,
}
```

. Only `Ctrl+tab` triggering is enabled in this case. What is wrong? I don't know.

To resolve these problems, I tried Snippets, making `HTML.sublime-snippet` file in `Sublime Text Build 3059 x64\Data\Packages\User` folder. I put

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eqq>
    $0$1
</eqq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eqq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eq>$1$0</eq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

. In this case only the first `<snippet>` is enabled. So I separately saved multiple snippet files.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eq>$0</eq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eq tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eq.sublime-snippet` file, and

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eq>$1$0</eq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eq{$PARAM1}</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eq{inline TeX equation} tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eqBraces.sublime-snippet` file, and

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eqq>
    $0
</eqq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eqq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eqq tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eqq.sublime-snippet` file, and

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eqq>
    $1$0
</eqq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eqq{$PARAM1}</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eqq{outline TeX equations} tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eqqBraces.sublime-snippet` file. But these don't resolve my problems completely either.

I tried something like `${1/\\/\/}`. But this doesn't work either. Uncomfortably using double `\` like `eq{\\alpha \\beta \\gamma}`, I can fix the unexpected escape \ problem.