# How to add custom auto completion in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-completion

How to add custom auto completion in Sublime Text 3?

Possible duplicate question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679535/how-to-add-custom-html-tags-in-sublime-text-3).

There is a good answer, but not quite complete. And reading official documents (Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation - Extending Sublime Text - [completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) and [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)), I am still wondering how to implement my customized HTML tag auto completion.

What I want is the below.

1. When I put

   ```
   eq(+tab)
   ```

   , I expect

   ```
   <eq>(Cursor)</eq>
   ```

   poped. (This simply works well with my multiple Snippet `.sublime-snippet` files separately saved.)
2. When I put

   ```
   eq{\alpha \beta \int}(+tab)
   ```

   , I expect

   ```
   <eq>\alpha \beta \int(Cursor position)</eq>
   ```

   poped. In this case, '\' is escaped and cursor position is at the beginning so that

   ```
   <eq>(Cursor position)alpha beta int</eq>
   ```

   is poped. Strange and uncomfortable result it is, since I want to render 'TeX' equation, i.e. math, in this tag.
3. When I put

   ```
   eqq(+tab)
   ```

   , I expect

   ```
   <eqq>
   (tab indented)(Cursor)
   </eqq>
   ```

   is poped. (This simply works well with my multiple Snippet `.sublime-snippet` files separately saved.)
4. When I put

   ```
   eqq{\alpha \beta \gamma \frac{1}{2}}(+tab)
   ```

   , I expect

   ```
   <eqq>
       \alpha \beta \gamma \frac{1}{2}(cursor position at the end of Tex Equation)
   </eqq>
   ```

   is poped. In this case, '\' is escaped also and no '\n\t' (newline, tab) is added so that

   ```
   <eqq>(cursor position)alpha beta gamma frac{1}{2}</eqq>
   ```

   is poped. And

   ```
   eqq{}(+tab)
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   <eqq>(Cursor position)</eqq>
   ```

   . Unlike `eqq(+tab)`, no '\n\t'.

Easiest way to implement these auto completions is to create `HTML.sublime-completions` file in `Sublime Text Build 3059 x64\Data\Packages\User` folder. (Since I use portable version of ST3 in Windows OS, the folder may be different when you installed ST3.) Filling the file with JSON text like

```
{
    "scope": "text.html - source - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "eq", "contents": "<eq>$1</eq>" },
        { "trigger": "eqq", "contents": "<eqq>\n\t$1\n</eqq>" }
    ]
}
```

. But `tab` triggering is not enabled, although my `Preferences - Settings - User` includes tab related features like

```
{
    [
        "Vintage",
        "BracketHighlighter",
        "SideBarEnhancements"
    ],
    "tab_completion": true,
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "use_tab_stops": false,
}
```

. Only `Ctrl+tab` triggering is enabled in this case. What is wrong? I don't know.

To resolve these problems, I tried Snippets, making `HTML.sublime-snippet` file in `Sublime Text Build 3059 x64\Data\Packages\User` folder. I put

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eqq>
    $0$1
</eqq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eqq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eq>$1$0</eq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

. In this case only the first `<snippet>` is enabled. So I separatly saved multiple snippet files.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eq>$0</eq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eq tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eq.sublime-snippet` file, and

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eq>$1$0</eq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eq{$PARAM1}</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eq{inline TeX equation} tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eqBraces.sublime-snippet` file, and

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eqq>
    $0
</eqq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eqq</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eqq tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eqq.sublime-snippet` file, and

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<eqq>
    $1$0
</eqq>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>eqq{$PARAM1}</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
    <description>eqq{outline TeX equations} tag to be rendered by MathJax</description>
</snippet>
```

in `eqqBraces.sublime-snippet` file. But these don't resolve my problems completely either.

I also asked this in [sublime User Echo](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/458420-how-to-add-custom-auto-completion-in-sublime-text-3/). Anyone who knows already this issue, please answer me.

I tried something like `${1/\\/\/}`. But this doesn't work either. Uncomfortably using double `\` like `eq{\\alpha \\beta \\gamma}`, I can fix the unexpected escape \ problem.

Answer (score -3):

1- If you want you can always add a plug in for sublime text. It's called Emmet and you can find it here [Emmet web page](http://emmet.io/)

It's simple to use for e.g. to write div + crtl + e and you will get `<div></div>`. Another way to use it is to put div.tagId + crtl + e and you'll get `<div id='tagId'> <div>`; if you want more than one you simply type div*2 and the same combination of keys and you'll get two divs.

For the other concerns I do not know how to solve them.

Comment: Your answer appears to be missing the examples.